# Digital predistortion of bipolar power amplifiers

Tags: electrical

What is the peak power limit of a signal beyond which a digital baseband  pre-distorter will not be able to correct for nonlinearities: P1 dB of an amplifier? P3 dB? and why is there a limit?

Comment: what is "P1 dB" or "P3 dB"? What's a pre-distorter?

Comment: You might as well ask what's an amplifier!

Comment: if I did, I would expect an answer to it. This sounds like specialized audio terminology or something.

Comment: It is fairly standard terminology in modern RF amplifiers. P1dB is the 1dB compression point, P3dB is the 3dB compression point.

Answer (score 0):

In the nice theoretical low signal power world of assuming everything is a cubic nonlinearity, it's possible to write a relation between P1dB and P3dB, IP3, ACLR, and other 'limits' on the amplifier performance.

However, at high power, where you want good power added efficiency, and digital predistortion techniques get useful, the shape of the distortion curve becomes very implementation technology dependent, and we discover that these limits are no longer proportional to each other.

'Perfect' predistortion with a completely stable predictable amplifier technology will of course work to any power within the capability of the amplifier. If a predistortion system is specifying a lower limit, then something other than that is going on. Maybe the predistortion implementation has been designed down to a cost. Maybe the amplifier it's been designed to be used with has unstable distortion levels with small temperature or supply voltage variations.

Remember that if an amplifier is producing a large amount of distortion, and the predistorter a large amount of 'anti-distortion', the resulting output distortion of the system is the small difference between two large quantities, so exquisitely sensitive to small errors in either.

Answer (score 0):

Depends a lot on how good you need the correction to be, and on how much drive you can both supply and the gate can tolerate.

Modern LDMOS for example has serious limits on maximum allowable gate voltage which limits the ability to predistort your way out of trouble.

General rule of thumb, 3dB you can probably do, but increasing the drive by 6dB will put you well into saturation (and will probably blow out the gate, especially if RF feedback is in play). The real win with predistortion is often in fixing up the PM more then the magnitude errors.